# Angular link two component

Tags: angular

Angular, there is a two component linking is there to show one of the form.

1. In one of the html( selector: 'app-custom-profile'), i have something bellow

```
     <app-custom-profile-form *ngIf="(user$ | async)?.uid" [user]="user$ | async"
       (submitted)="onSubmit($event)"></app-custom-profile-form>
```

Here am linking app-custom-profile-form, with app-custom-profile.   app-custom-profile-form  tag is other component, there i have defined  like bellow(step 2)

2. In other component( selector: 'app-custom-profile-form')

```
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="updateProfileForm"></form>
```

> In the above scenario, am extending Currentcomponent extends
> ParentComponent, in parentComponent we have all the logic like
> submit() action, when am hitting submit button here, action is not
> happening. Usually if we extend parentComponent, all the
> methods/actions will come, what was the mistake here. Please help me
> on this. Thanks.